# Beginning boating

Tags: boats

Assume I am completely naïve of boating concerns, that I know the following:

- There are things that float and carry stuff across the water called boats.
- A boat needs something to make it move. Some have motors, some catch wind in sails, some you move yourself with paddles.

**What are the things I should know (or do, or get, etc.) before clumsily rushing into boating?**

I don't know what I don't know, so please point me in the right direction.

A commenter has suggested that the answers would be different for the different types of boats. As such, I am making questions for the types outlined above, and answers here should be about generic information which applies to all boating in general (I assume there is a lot of overlap), and can link to those other questions as well. So see also:

- [Beginning paddle boating](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20293/beginning-paddle-boating)

*Please treat this as a gateway for beginners who don't know what questions to ask to start with and as a lynch-pin to link together any other relevant Q&As on the site. In fact, linking in any other Q&As on the site which really should be read by the beginning boater would be great.*

Comment: Hi Aaron! This is a good idea, but unfortunately, I don't think it fits the SE model of detailed individual questions seeking specific answers. The [help] discourages questions which are generic, open-ended, vague, or too many questions at a time. Experience shows that people answer pieces (which has already happened here); answers get repetitive or lost; we don't know how to vote; long comment discussions happen; new users get confused. Splitting it up and linking to others would work. I could be wrong, and I mean no offense!

Comment: The answers are going to be different for the major categories of boats - person-powered, wind-powered and motor-powered.

Comment: Hi Aaron - this is, unfortunately, waaaay too broad. In fact to fully answer it requires a course or a series of books. Please follow @Sue's advice.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I actually know a little bit more than what the question claims. I don't know enough to be safe out on all the waterways, but I do know just enough at least to know an answer to this does not require a series of books. I have more to say, but I'm going to refrain for fear of saying anything negative out of my annoyance at what has happened here.

Comment: For the record, I don't mind if edits get made to improve the question **as asked**, however, I very specifically am **against** edits that will change the nature of the question, and anything that could reduce the scope of the question would change the nature of the question. "I am a noob of noobs. Here is what little I know. Can you help me get into this activity? You don't need to give all the directions, or even give me a compass bearing... just point me in the right direction." *That is one of the most important type of questions that SE can have a Q&A for.* In my opinion, anyway.

Comment: @Sue This question cannot be split up and linked, as splitting up and linking was what I was one of the things I was hoping this question could help with, and this question is the basis of that, the foundation. This question cannot really be split up any further. At best, I could remove the "here are some ideas to get you started" part with the hypothetical questions, but that's all since the question really is just "I know practically nothing. Where do I start?"

Comment: @Aaron - the problem here isn't with what you want to know. It's because the SE framework makes it only work with single questions that can be answered, not with a group of questions. So I think your edit really helps... It is still broad though, so I think we need to look at a bit of further editing.

Comment: As an example, I used to teach the first stages of the RYA sailing school, and after a couple of weeks on the water, I would still count the sailors as beginners - even though we had taught them a pretty broad syllabus...

Comment: You might be mentioning something that would be part of an appropriate answer. I don't understand what you said. What is "RYA sailing school?" You mention "first stages of..." did you mean generally (early in the classes), or are there official stages of this RYA sailing school? This is part of my point: You cannot close or hold questions and expect anything positive to come from it when the asker does not know what else to ask. A fine answer could say conditions/decisions to make first (paddle/motor, lake/ocean...), and to say it depends on that, so other questions can be asked. That's an ans